# Display content of file in dashboard Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, text-files, shinydashboard

I am trying to display help for user in shiny dashboard from text file. However I can't control displaying of new lines("\n"). They are in text file and in the text but shiny does not want to display them.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiny converts all elements to HTML, which does not render the newline (`\n`) character. In order to create a line break, you can wrap each line in a set of HTML paragraph tags using the `p()` function.

This means that instead of using `renderText()` and `textOutput` you will need to use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` in your app.

A full example of how to convert newline characters to paragraph tags is given below.

```
require(stringi)
require(shiny)

# write text file with standard newline characters
str <- 'These are words\nwith newline characters\n\nthat do not render.'
write(x = str, file = 'Data.txt')

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4('Reading raw text from file:'),
  textOutput('textWithNewlines'), # text with newline characters output

  h4('Converting text to list of paragraph tags'), 
  uiOutput('textWithHTML') # ui output as a list of HTML p() tags
)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$textWithNewlines <- renderText({
    rawText <- readLines('Data.txt')
    return(rawText)
  })

  ### SOLUTION ###
  output$textWithHTML <- renderUI({
    rawText <- readLines('Data.txt') # get raw text

    # split the text into a list of character vectors
    #   Each element in the list contains one line
    splitText <- stringi::stri_split(str = rawText, regex = '\\n')

    # wrap a paragraph tag around each element in the list
    replacedText <- lapply(splitText, p)

    return(replacedText)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```